# Source Informatica PowerCenter

Tags: informatica, informatica-powercenter

I am starting to use computer science powercenter, I know that I can see the dependencies of my objects, however, it is not clear to me how to know if my source is an independent database or there is a process that loads it previously since I am confused with the definition of all parents and all the children.I would appreciate if someone could support me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to check if your source is loaded by a process,  show the dependencies of your source table as a target then see if there is any mapping in the result.